# Solving system of ODE with boundary condition

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve a system of Ordinary Differential Equation(ODE) using python. I have a system of five ODE with five variables ***(T,U,V,W,I)***. It changes with the time ***(t)***. So far the code below works fine with python package ***odeint***.

I want to solve the same system of 5 ODE using ***solve_bvp*** having boundary condition **y(0)=0** and **y(1)=1**. I tried it several times with **solve_bvp** but not successful.

Secondly, I also want to know that is it possible to solve multi-point boundary values using **sovle_bvp**. If not then is there any other way in python to solve it. What i read in [**solve_bvp**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_bvp) is that it this function numerically solves a first order system of ODEs subject to two-point boundary conditions. Thanks

```
from scipy import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from operator import itemgetter
from pylab import *
import itertools
from numpy import zeros_like
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


initial_condi = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
t = np.arange(0,60,1)

def equation(w, t):
    T, U, V,W,I = w
    dT = 0.9*I*1*10.24 - T*0.0012
    dU = V*T*0.0154 - U*1*0.81
    dV = W*0.1*0.12 + U*1*0.81 
    dW= V*1.64 + 0.7 - W*U*1591.5*1
    dI= T*0.0012 + 0.8- 0.9*I*1*10.24 
    return dT,dU,dV,dW, dI

    result_init = odeint(equation, initial_condi, t)

plt.plot(t, result_i[:,0], 'r--')
plt.plot(t, result_i[:,1], 'r--')
plt.plot(t, result_i[:,2], 'r--')
plt.plot(t, result_i[:,3], 'r--')
plt.plot(t, result_i[:,4], 'r--')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you add your most evolved try for `solve_bvp`, so that one can see what you intended and where you may have gone wrong? No, `solve_bvp` does not have multi-point capabilities. You could always formulate such conditions as a system of equations for an `odeint` solution and apply some non-linear solver from the `scipy.optimize` module.

Comment: The way I was doing it was completely wrong I was just using solve_bvp instead of odeint but i don't know how to initialise the above mentioned boundary values. So what about the hidden conditions or infinite conditions if we want to solve such BVP.

Comment: I think you are speaking about a different kind of class there. Hidden conditions I only know in DAE systems, and what are "infinite conditions"? As  for the initialization, you have to take a guess. In general the overall problem is non-linear, so it may have different solutions. With the initial curve you can try to select one of them. This is a little like Newton's method where different initial points will lead to different solutions or to no solution at all (in reasonable time or never).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Pretty helpful thanks and what are your thoughts about solve_bvp in comparison with Matlab  bvp4c. I have seen some problems of solve_bvp on stake overflow and other forums, from which it seems to me that Python bvp package is not too mature as of Matlab.

Comment: I do not know if it is in the documentation or if it was some remark of the developer in the but-tracker, but solve_bvp is considered quite experimental, and solve_ivp is also not really suitable as workhorse. There are stability issues, and questions about the balancing of the errors in the boundary conditions and the errors in the implicit ODE solver steps,...

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to code the above problem for me?

Comment: It is still not clear what problem it is you are trying to solve. You give boundary conditions for some `y`, but there is not `y` component in the state. What other boundary conditions are there, you need as many as you have components in the state.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry I am in learning phase so I don't have a very good idea of DE. In the above equations the boundary conditions should be of the state variables ? Variables like T,U,V,W,I ? Am I right or correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, just as the initial conditions in the code give the initial values of `T(0), U(0), V(0),W(0),I(0)`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann What if I change the boundary conditions from y  to T(0),U(0),V(0),W(0),I(0) =1 and T(1),U(1),V(1),W(1),I(1)=2. Does it make any sense ?

Comment: You can only have as many boundary conditions as the state has components. Free, variable parameters in the ODE also count as components. So you either have to select 5 of these conditions, or find 5 parameters in the ODE that you can declare as free, to be determined in the solution process.